# Writer a Server like Tomcat in Java

Tags: java

How hard would it be to write a server like Tomcat in Java or another programming language?

I have been enjoying working with UDP and TCP sockets molding them into simple client and server to pass data around my computer, and I was wonder how hard would it be to write a server from the ground up??

I know that there has been at lest one OS written in Java using the JVM in the parts where it would normal be written in C or ASM.

Comment: Are you talking about an OS or some sort of software, or software middleware? What do you want the server to do?

Comment: Go to: http://tomcat.apache.org/ , look at the source. Then you can make your own estimation.

Comment: A server like: apache, iPlanet, tomcat, etc...

Comment: But when I think of a server like BSD pops in my head

Comment: I cannot find or view the source code, the "RAW" source code

Comment: Sort of depends on how much of "tomcat" you consider to be "tomcat"  Do you mean just the actual web container?  What about the JSP engine?  The servlet container? 'Tomcat' is a lot of pieces :)

Comment: If you want to explore a simpler servlet container, take a look at [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/).

Comment: Everything as a whole piece... I just used tomcat as an example a well known server that is used for doing JSP's and networking.

Answer (score 2):

[Java is very capable when writing client / server programs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).  While networking is not exactly easy, there are many tool kits which make writing such programs much harder, with more prerequisite knowledge.

As far as a "Tomcat" type server, you would also need to learn a lot about class loading, to keep the "trees" of java classes identified as "applications" from cross-communicating.  Class loading takes a bit more time to get right, mostly because it is a bit of work writing up a decent set of tests to really assure yourself that the classes are in the right places, and the security is *really* there.

Is it a bit of work?  Yes.  But exactly how much work depends very heavily on the details.  A simple server socket and the code to accept connections could be written by an experienced programmer in a day (or at least under a week).  Implementing the protocol (bits to be expected and sent) will take longer, depending on how many "features" the protocol supports.  This is why all the "example" client / server Java programs are basically "echo" servers, time servers, or some other *very trivial* protocol.

If you want a sophisticated threading model to assure the server scales across extra cores, or handles requests quickly even when processing other requests that take a relatively long time, then keep adding more time (as you discard simple threading models for more complex threading models).

By now you will have decided that a few things need to be configurable, and *how* you decide to configure them will determine how much more time you need to invest in your configuration subsystem.

The real cost; however, is not in the writing of the application, it will be in the testing and bug fixing.  For every line of code you write to work under normal circumstances, many unconsidered circumstances will eventually slow things down.  To pay some of that known, yet often unplanned, extra time up front, use test driven development to keep yourself from paying an enormous testing debt right when you want to say "I'm finished".

Comment: I know this is going to sound bad but I have to ask, but.. What about if I wanted to use just the Java library and write all of the source code my self; like building a car from the ground up?

Comment: Even auto manufacturers use semi-processed starting materials.  They don't grab a shovel to start digging for ore to refine into metal to cast into a part to make a car.  If you want to start at the level of using only the core Java library, it is _already_ quite capable of implementing a client / server program in under a hundred lines of code.  It is getting it to do more that takes, well _more_ time.

Comment: This would be more to help me learn about it, I am a computer science major with a minor in math and networking.

Comment: I fully understand where you are coming from, having been a computer science major with a minor in math.  My recommendation is to start here, at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/TOC.html as even if you have _more_ knowledge of networking than they assume, you will _never_ learn Java networking by ignoring the basics as they apply in a Java environment.  Once you have the basics down, bits and pieces of your networking theory will be useful in designing an unambiguous protocol, but you will still learn something in the transition.

Comment: Sure you could.  I can't promise to reply, or even to reply quickly. ebuck70 (at) yahoo (dot) com

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a great project for a student because it can teach you a ton about programming.  In particular, it will help you learn about all of the little (and not little) problems that come when you try to work on a project.  When I was in college I wanted to write my own simple SMTP server from scratch.  I had to learn the protocol, network programming, threading and a ton of other details that I didn't think through when I started.  I think it was very useful (and time consuming) and I felt like I had actually accomplished something when I was done.  I also learned why people use existing libraries and tend to focus on building on others work instead of starting from scratch but I didn't learn that until the end.

My advice is to give yourself a specific and seemingly small goal and **make sure you finish it**.  The most important lesson comes in being the kind of person who completes what they start.  Lots of people have great ideas but executing (and finishing) even small ideas is always what's most important.

I wouldn't pick a Servlet Container like Tomcat because the Servlet spec is a beast.  I would find something you're interested in, limit the scope and go to work.  My friends wanted a mailing list so I started there.  Maybe you're interested in HTTP or you want a way for your phone to play MP3s on your computer.  It helps to stay motivated if you're solving a problem for yourself (even if a "real" solution already exists).

Good Luck!

You can do it!

Comment: This quest is not about simple cell phone application market place..This is for purely scientific purposes to develop more cutting edge computer tech that would help increase information theory by computation and networking; learning the inner working on the internet and what possible lay in waiting for a programmer to find. Like view all incoming data going throughout the sockets of the network. Computer and networking theory is still just beginning, no one know what the internet is truly capable of.

Comment: I think giving yourself a project even a seemingly small one is a great way to learn a lot more than you might think.  Take the Cell Phone example above - let's think through what needs to be written in order for it to work.  If we ignore the GUI, the Phone needs a client library capable of talking to a server and issuing commands like "start", "pause", "stop", "select song".  What other commands does it need?  How does it send those to the computer? It also needs to find a computer to connect to.  How does it search? How does it select an appropriate computer?

Comment: The computer needs a server to listen for commands and a way to manipulate the computer.  How does it notify clients that it exists?  Which commands does it accept? How does it handle errors? I think there is a lot to learn about networking just from this simple app.  If your goal is to increase information theory you might also want to think about what published protocols exist for doing this kind of thing.  UPNP is an example.  Perhaps implementing a client/server will help you understand what the pros & cons of this protocol are and how you can help improve it.